# Does $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^4}{y}$ exist?

Tags: analysis, limits

Does $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^4}{y}$ exist? I don't think so, therefore I try to find a sequence $(x_n,y_n)\to(0,0)$ such that the limit of $f(x_n,y_n)$ in $(0,0)$ does not exist. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to do it with a single sequence of points, and want to avoid the line $y=0$, it can be done this way.

If $n$ is odd, then $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

If $n$ is even, then $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y=\frac{1}{n^4}$.

However, using two different paths is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to find two different sequences, $s_n=(a_n,b_n)$ and $t_n=(x_n,y_n)$ that converge to $(0,0)$ but $f(s_n)$ and $f(t_n)$ converge to different numbers.

For example, $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ and $(\frac{1}{n^{1/4}},\frac1n)$. Both go to $(0,0)$ but the function goes to different values.

Comment: Why would you **have** to do it that way? Finding a sequence that is not cauchy will also work no?